# sort list python by same index

Tags: python, list

I am trying to sort my data in arrays. My python code gives the following output:

```
Value List: [['house'], ["'tW'"], ['6.998332153088995']]
Insert at array index: 3
[['6.998332153088995']]


Value List: [['house'], ["'Total'"], ['91.40121710449374']]
Insert at array index: 11
[['91.40121710449374']]


Value List: [['garden'], ["'flower'"], ['0.1525635807425692']]
Insert at array index: 0
[['0.1525635807425692']]


Value List: [['garden'], ["'gras'"], ['0.31921114287979435']]
Insert at array index: 12
[['0.31921114287979435']]
```

Now I want to write these values to a .txt file, but I want to order them in the following way:

```
#region tW     Total    flower    gras
house   6.9983 91.40121
garden                  0.152     0.312
```

That means that the first item of the value list stays at the beginning and is filled with the value at the specific position. But I do not want to have double entries of e.g house, house should be only in one line.

but unfortunately list.insert(position, value) is not working in my case. I provide you here now my minimal code that is giving me the above output:

```
newarraylist = []
print("Value List: " + str(list4))
print("Insert at array index: " + str(save_values_to_file(list4)))
newarraylist.insert(save_values_to_file(list4), list4[2])
print(newarraylist)
```

Hope someone could help me with that beginner problem

Comment: How are your lists 'read' by the program? Do you read them from file, or did you store them somewhere within the code? I would be interested in seeing where they exactly come from?

Comment: The lists are getting stored within the program. Unfortunately I cannot provide more code.

Comment: What should happen when list5 were for example `[['house'], ["'tW'"], ['12.3425114131']]`? By the way, I was not asking for more code, rather for input data in the format your program is using it.

Comment: Ah now I understand your point. It cannot happen that duplicate elements will occur for house, also for the other regions. It can only be that a few values are missing like flower. But I want to fill the values regarding the position I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty tricky to do, but here is something that works. First I formatted your data (hence my question) into Python format: a list of lists. It is a bit cumbersome because each data element is a list of itself, but so be it:

```
lsts=[
[['house'], ["'tW'"], ['6.998332153088995']],
[['house'], ["'Total'"], ['91.40121710449374']],
[['garden'], ["'flower'"], ['0.1525635807425692']],
[['garden'], ["'gras'"], ['0.31921114287979435']]
]
```

The idea is to use a header list to count how many different 'properties' there are, and a to use a dictionary for the 'regions', initialized with enough empty string to fit all properties.

```
headers = [lst[1][0] for lst in lsts]                           # a list with the headers ['tW', 'Total', 'flower', 'gras']
regions = set([lst[0][0] for lst in lsts])                      # a set of the regions: {'house', 'garden'}
valdict = {region:len(headers) * [''] for region in regions}    # a dict: {region:['', '', '', ''], } where the list has the same number of items as the header list

for lst in lsts:
    valdict[lst[0][0]][headers.index(lst[1][0])] = lst[2][0]    # in the dict, change one of the empty list items
```

The output section first prints the variables, and then everything as a table:

```
# RAW OUTPUT
print(headers)
for region, values in valdict.items():
    print(region, values)

#PRETTY PRINT (a bit clumsy, but it shows a nice table format
print('\nPretty print\n')

print('{:10}'.format(''), end='')
for header in headers:
    print('{:10}'.format(header), end='')
for region in regions:
    print('\n{:10}'.format(region), end='')
    for val in valdict[region]:
        if val == '':
            print('{:<10}'.format(val), end='')                 # print empty strings in list
        else:
            print('{:<10.4f}'.format(float(val)), end='')       # format print strings as floats
```

***Final output***

```
["'tW'", "'Total'", "'flower'", "'gras'"]
garden ['', '', '0.1525635807425692', '0.31921114287979435']
house ['6.998332153088995', '91.40121710449374', '', '']

Pretty print

          'tW'      'Total'   'flower'  'gras'
garden                        0.1526    0.3192
house     6.9983    91.4012
```

The only thing is that because I used a dict, the order of `garden` and `house` is undetermined. Of course you can sort the dict or you can use `SortedDict` to shape the data further.

*PS: I'm quite open to a more elegant solution ;-)*